# Cannot set RecycleView Adapter in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment like this

```
...

public class Dashboard extends Fragment{
    private RecyclerView mTopSellersListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_dashboard, container, false);
        mTopSellersListView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.topSellersListView);
        return view;
    }

    public void setTopSellersListView(MyRecycleAdapter adapter){
        mTopSellersListView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mTopSellersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mTopSellersListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mTopSellersListView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        mTopSellersListView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
}
```

I have total 4 fragment, all of them can be switch in MainActivity by a bottombar used this method, when user tap on menu, it will replace current fragment with another one (Default: Dashboard):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDashboardFragment = new Dashboard();
        mOrdersFragment = new Orders();
        mProductsFragment = new Products();
        mSettingFragment = new Setting();
        settingMenu(savedInstanceState);
}

...

public void selectMenu(String menu){
    Fragment fr = null;
    switch (menu) {
        case "Dashboard":
            fr = mDashboardFragment;
            break;
        case "Orders":
            fr = mOrdersFragment;
            break;
        case "Products":
            fr = mProductsFragment;
            break;
        case "Setting":
            fr = mSettingFragment;
            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I access the setTopSellersListView() in another class (not activity class)

```
MainActivity.mDashboardFragment.setTopSellersListView(mProductAdapter);
```

and got NullPointerExceptions at mTopSellersListView.setHasFixedSize(true)

Comment: NullPointerExceptions  should be occurred if you tried to call the "null" object's method . That's mean your mTopSellersListView was already null when you call the setTopSellersListView() method. Please provide your code where you call this method. If it is possible, provide more code of your activity class as possible. And also all the stacktrace of this error in your logcat

Comment: @LongRanger I've fix it thank to your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by call setTopSellersListView() in onStart() in Fragment and it works great

Answer (score 0):

First set your layoutManager than use setHasFizedSize(true).Since the layoutManager determines the size of your recyclerView.

Comment: Still got crash :(

Comment: This does not make sense since the problem is nullpointerexception. Normally it should be related to some null object. Not the problem of the order of statement. And also the set function should be only for assigning value to the attribute of the recyclerview without any further action. As you can see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize%28boolean%29. It does nothing more than assigning value so it should not be the reason why this problem occurred.